# GPO to deploy null printer

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

So it is possible to add a new local printer on a windows 10 workstation and designate that you'd like to create a new port, enter 'NUL', and then assign a generic driver and have a "printer" that doesn't actually print. This is important in overcoming a crucial limitation in one of our core software providers. I need to now deploy this for the entire organization, but I'm upon inspection of the group policy it doesn't seem to allow me to create a nul port, nor can I assign a printer without declaring a path.

Is there a way to deploy a Null printer object through group policy?

Comment: Hi, why not using LPT1 port ?

Comment: In my case, because of the software bug we are fighting, LPT1 results in a 3 minute timeout during transactions.